# How to dynamically addJPanels into JscrollPane that has been dynamically added to the JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing

I have a requirement for that i need to dynamically add JPanels inside JScorllPane that has been dynamically added to the Jtabbed pane.
There are 2 Buttons one for 'Add' and another is 'More'.
'Add' button adds new Tab with scroll pane along with one dynamic panel which occupies the entire tab. 
When i click 'More' it should add more panels into the same tab but I cant able to add further Panels into the same tab.

The entire tab is occupied by the first panel.

jButton3-ADD
jButton2-More

```
 private void init() {
            jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(new JPanel());`enter code here`
            add(jScrollPane1);

    }


private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int i=0;
        AddTab=hMSComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();
        String uomCode = hMSComboBox1.getSelectedRow()[AddTab];
        JScrollPane jScrollPane1=new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(new JPanel());
        tabbedPane1.add(jScrollPane1);
        tabbedPane1.setTitleAt(i, uomCode);
        tabbedPane1.setVisible(true);
        tabbedPane1.validate();
        i++;
        RecepieIngred Pan1=new RecepieIngred();
        Pan1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 350));
        Pan1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        JPanel view = ((JPanel)jScrollPane1.getViewport().getView());
        view.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 12, 12));
        view.add(Pan1);
        view.validate();
    }     

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

                RecepieIngred Pan1=new RecepieIngred();
                Pan1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 600));
                Pan1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
                JPanel view = ((JPanel)jScrollPane1.getViewport().getView());
                view.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 12, 12));
                view.add(Pan1);
                view.validate();


        //add(jButton2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }
```

Comment: Where do you add your JTabbedPane to the GUI? I think that you'll want to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since this would be the best and quickest way to get folks to fully understand your problem and then help you. Also consider posting links to images (not to pages) that show what you're trying to achieve and what you're actually achieving.

Comment: Also, you will want to improve your variable and method naming so that your code complies with Java naming standards, and so that your code becomes self commenting. For instance method names such as jButton2ActionPerformed are confusing, and much better is to use something like addAdditionalPanelActionPerformed(...) or something like this. Note that class names all start with an upper-case letter and method/variable names with a lower-case letter.

Comment: Also, whenever I see multiple components being added this way, I wonder if the original poster really wants to use a JList or a JTable.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your valuable suggestions, i will follow the standard in my future codings, i want to add the tabbed pane into a Panel

Comment: `"... i want to add the tabbed pane into a Panel..."` -- but do you? And again, where? Please improve this question so that it's answerable. Again, please create and post a decent [mcve] (please check out the link as it's important).

Comment: what i want to do is i have to take a value from JCombo using add button and add button needs to create a tabbed pane using that value. Then the tabbed pane should include a Jscrollpane which in-turn includes many small panels. The add button need to do all these. when i click on more button i want to add small panels inside the same scrollpane which is loaded by add button. if i select a new value in combo again i need to add another tab with scrollpane which includes several small panels. I dnt have any idea to proceed this

Comment: When I see `"I dnt have any idea to proceed this"`, I have to wonder if you're taking too big of a bite here. I suggest that you stop and re-assess, and then break the big problem into small steps and try to solve each small step, one at a time. Then if you are still stuck in a small step, come back with your problem, your code, and we'll have an easier time helping you. Unfortunately your current code is unintelligible to us, and your problem has too many steps to allow some of us (me at least) to venture a decent answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biggest error you have is that in your jButton3ActionPerformed callback you are referring to '**jScrollPane1**'. I suspect you have a class member with the same name as you are referring to it in the other callback jButton2ActionPerformed. The problem you have however is that jButton3ActionPerformed will be using the local instance in that method (same name as your global member but JRE will take the local scope). So in actual fact both callbacks are referring to different scrollpane references.

Also, I'd rather use a BoxLayout with Y-AXIS for your panel.

Comment: Hi JGA,        How can i conclude this? i dont have any idea. when i click more the panel gets added but it removes the previous tab loaded by Add.

Comment: @Sakthi: he can't conclude anything, none of us can, until you improve your question.